# How do I create default tag for my automated DockerFile build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have create a Bitbucket Repo called songkongdocker, and create a DockerFile

https://bitbucket.org/ijabz/songkongdocker/src/master/

This is linked as an *automated build* to my http://docker.com account

I then tried to use it within Docker and I got

```
C:\Users\Paul>docker pull ijabz/songkongdocker
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: manifest for ijabz/songkongdocker:latest not found
```

So I then tried using default and that didn't work either

```
C:\Users\Paul>docker pull ijabz/songkongdocker:default
Error response from daemon: manifest for ijabz/songkongdocker:default not found
```

What do I have to do, sorry if this is a stupid question, (first time using Docker).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I refer to [the page of your image](https://hub.docker.com/r/ijabz/songkongdocker/tags/), there is no published image.

You have to [push](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/) a version of your image first.
When pulling an image, if you don't specify a tag explicitly, then the `latest` tag is assumed.

To obtain an image to push, you can manually:

- [build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) one from a `Dockerfile`
- [commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) a container

Otherwise I just looked at [docker automated builds](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/) (that I did not know) and, looking at [the build status tab](https://hub.docker.com/r/ijabz/songkongdocker/builds/), it seems your image is currently building. But since there is no log displayed, perhaps the build is stuck. I do not know...

You could try to build the image manually to check what happen.
You can build your image locally by installing docker on your workstation, putting your Dockerfile anywhere on your workstation and running `docker build -t songkongdocker .` from the directory where you put the Dockerfile

Comment: Hi, okay no I havent 'pushed' but where do I do that, I see from your link there is a docker push command but my docker container contains nothing, the DockerFile is in BitBucket so I dont understand how I get to Docker to push it backer to DockerHub ?

Comment: a while ago I came across the trigger build on the automated build page, but its taking a long time, first it waited in a queque for half hour, then it has been build for nearly an hour, dont know how long it is meant to take.

Comment: So to build manually, do I need to get Docker container within docker and then get Docker file and build ?

Comment: okay now resolved, my dockerfile had errors in it preventing automated build.